# What is the value of bessel functions at 0?

Tags: special-functions

I would like to know what the value of the bessel functions of the first kind and the modified bessel of the first kind is at 0.

I think for order 0 they are 1 and for orders greater than 0 they are 0.

ie

$J_0 (0) = 1$ and $J_v(0) = 0$ for $v$ > 0

$I_0 (0) = 1$ and $I_v(0) = 0$ for $v$ > 0

Is the above correct?

Comment: Yes. I've just verified the results with *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bessel and modified Bessel of the first kind can be expressed in series form as
\begin{align}
J_{\nu}(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k! (\nu + k)!} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2k+\nu}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
I_{\nu}(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! (\nu + k)!} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2k+\nu}.
\end{align}
The first term of each is
\begin{align}
J_{\nu}(x) &= \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{\nu} + \cdots \\
I_{\nu}(x) &= \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{\nu} + \cdots 
\end{align}
Since $0^{\nu} = 0$ for $\nu \geq 1$ and $0^{0}= 1$ for $\nu = 0$ then it is evident that $J_{0}(0) = 1$ and $J_{\nu}(0) = 0$ for $\nu \geq 0$. Applying the same to the modified function yields the similar result.

Comment: Should the couple of "ν ≥ 0" just be "ν > 0"? (i.e. without the "or equal to", since the ν = 0 case is separate)